# Wifi not working- Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, wireless

Wifi was working properly on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 until recently the wifi icon disappeared from Ubuntu. I've tried everything mentioned in other threads but I couldn't solve it.

```
prajval10@prajval:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried this as well:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I enabled the driver in Settings as well.

[Additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neu2u.png)

`modinfo wl | grep vermagic
vermagic:       4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions`

`sudo modprobe -fv wl
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error`

Comment: Secure boot disabled in BIOS?

Comment: `DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.32~14.04.2+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic`

Seems like secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `modinfo wl | egrep 'file|varmagic'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I've included the results for the above command

Comment: I had a typo, what result for `modinfo | grep vermagic`

Comment: `prajval10@prajval:~$ modinfo | grep vermagic
modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename`

@Jeremy31

Comment: @Jeremy31 could you help me out please? My kernel version is 4.4.0-116-generic and gcc version is  5.4.1 20160904.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi works with `kernel: 4.4.0-112-generic` but not with `4.4.0-116-generic`. This seems to be a known issue, so I'll stick to using `4.4.0-112-generic` for now

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, or should we say workaround :-)

Comment: No problem! :) I will keep this thread open because I would like a solution for `4.4.0-116-generic`.